# Connect MPU6050 in pins other than A4 & A5

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

I need to use a MPU6050 gyro and a Ultrasonic sensor for my project. My Arduino Uno did not come with separate SDA and SCL pins, so I have to use the A4 and A5 pins for that purpose, and I have connected the Ultrasonic sensor with them. 
\With no SDA and SCL pins available, and A4 and A5 already occupied, is there any way to use other pins like A0 and A1 for SDA and SCL connections?

Comment: Have you seen the software I2C library [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary/)?

Comment: Why not move the ultrasonic to other pins? BTW: SCL/SDA and A4/A5 are physically the same pins - you can't use both at once.

Answer (score 0):

A4/A5 are the I2C Bus. You will connect multiple I2C devices in parallel to the pins. I would suggest wiring them Uno to device to device, with pullup resistors 3.3K or 4.7K pullup resistors to Vcc on the last device.

Answer (score 0):

Your Uno did not come with seperate SDA and SCL pins, because on the microcontroller, that is used on the Uno (Atmega328p) these pins are shared too. That is a common practice, because not everyone needs I2C, but may want more analog pins.

You have basically 2 ways to go here:

- You can leave the ultrasonic sensor, where it is connected now, and try it with a software I2C library like [this one](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary/), that can be used on nearly any other pin pair. Note, that in this case the I2C protocol will be completely handled in software, which puts a bigger workload on the microcontroller and may need other resources, that you want to use later (for example it might use timer hardware).
- You can put the ultrasonic sensor to other pins, because it is not limited anyway. You can use any digital pin pair. The MPU can then be connected to A4 and A5, as they are the pins of the hardware I2C interface. IMO this is the cleaner solution, since the core of the I2C protocol will be handled in hardware without the code doing anything for it. The code just puts the data into a buffer, not more. Also it will not use any other hardware inside of the microcontroller.

Which of these options is the best here is up to you. Maybe you have a good reason to not move the ultrasonic sensor to other pins.

Comment: Uh oops: The LCD with I2C is connected to the A4 and A5, not the ultrasonic sensor. So I guess I'll have to go with the first one?

Comment: You can connect multiple devices to the same I2C bus. It is a bus and every device has an address.